# Expecting RBRACE? What is CSS Lint talking about?

Tags: css

CSS Lint thinks there is something wrong here. And so does the W3C CSS Validator. They are probably right and I am wrong, but can someone please help me understand why this is wrong?

**CSS:**

```
.my-class {
    width:  calc(((100% - 15%) / 3 - 1px) * 3 + 10%); /* for 3 columns */
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Expected RBRACE at line 2, col 22.
```

By the way, browsers seem to be more on my side.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a problem with CSS Lint currently. Just a bit of [bad parsing](http://github.com/stubbornella/csslint/issues/267).

CSS3 `calc` is however still not a recommendation by W3C, but it looks very likely to be a standard soon. A warning would be the appropriate message from CSS Lint, of course.

Comment: Do you happen to mean "still NOT a recommendation by W3C" or it's just me who is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I happen to mean that. Edited. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the editing, Itay. I should learn to make links here.

Comment: Yhea, I think that the good look of the content is very important. It not only improves the readability of the content but it also makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this article](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/603) it seems that `calc()` isn't supported very well.

> **2 years ago**
>   *The parser does not support calc()*

It seems like it is sort of fixed, but not entirely.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a problem with csslint. Just a bit bad parsing:

    https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint/issues/267

Comment: Updated issue link has been updated as the original has been closed. https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/603

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the fact that arithmetics is an *experimental feature* of CSS and is certainly not in any of the *CSS Specifications*.

Those services are created according to CSS specifications and no wonder they found an error in your code. The entire statement is invalid according to the specs.

Comment: Thanks, Itay, yes I know, but I would expect a warning saying calc is not supported instead of this. ;-)

Comment: @Leo Yes, you are right, but I guess they haven't implemented that warning yet.

Comment: Looks like they got the parsing wrong. See my comment to to jsve.

Comment: @Leo Since you found the answer, consider posting it?

Comment: Thanks Itay. I think that will be more clear for others, yes.